# Make forward-list search for specific symbol only

Tags: search, list, motion

Is there a way to make `forward-list` and `backward-list`search for specific symbols (such as `「」『』`) only?

I have code that make use of these functions to iterate through `「」『』` pairs in plain text. But `forward-list` would apply to `()《》〈〉` etc. as well, which makes the code very inefficient.

`(re-search-forward "「\\|『" nil t)` is not the optimal solution because I am dealing with balanced pairs of quotes, and only have to deal with the outer-most paretheses. For instance, `forward-list` would stop 2 times in the scenario below, while `re-search-forward` would take 4.

`forward-list`:

> 「『』『』」1「」2

`re-search-forward`:

> 「1『2』『3』」「4」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own temporary syntax table. Just start with a newly created character table with default nil entries and modify only those syntax entries you need.

The following Elisp function demonstrates that.
It creates a temporary syntax table with the syntax you want and sends you into recursive edit.

You can then interactively try commands like `forward-list` with the binding <kbd>C-M-n</kbd>.

Exit recursive edit with <kbd>C-M-c</kbd> when you are done.

```el
(defun my-stops ()
  "Test modified syntax table with `recursive-edit'."
  (interactive)
  (with-syntax-table (make-char-table 'syntax-table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\「 "(」")
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\」 ")「")
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\『 "(』")
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\』 ")『")
    (let ((header-line-format "Test the modified syntax in recursive edit. Leave with M-C-c."))
      (recursive-edit))))
```

If you want to avoid the creation of a syntax table at each function call just store it in a global variable and re-use it a la

```el
(defvar my-syntax-table nil)

(defun my-stops ()
 (with-syntax-table (or my-syntax-table
                        (setq my-syntax-table (let ((table (make-char-table 'syntax-table)))
                                                 (modify-syntax-entry ?\「 "(」" table)
                                                 ...
                                                 table)))
  ...))
```

---

Independently of what I wrote above I would actually use a combination of `re-search-forward` and `forward-sexp` instead of modifying the syntax table for a task like that.